# Deallocate UIViewController after Segue

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to transition from one view controller to other but without any animation. On the storyboard, I chose Push segue and on the right panel, unchecked the "Animate" option. Then in the code, whenever I wanted to make a transition, I did:
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("TestSegue", sender: nil)

Now the problem is that the previous view controllers aren't getting deallocated and the memory keeps on increasing.

Question:

1) Is my method of using segues without animation correct?

2) How do I deallocate the view controller from the memory after segue is performed?

Kindly help me solve these issues.

Note: I am using Swift

Comment: is it increasing, when you navigate back? do u use unwinding?

Comment: no, just another push Segue. Should I use unwinding?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is a problem with the way you are performing a segue to another ViewController. I think you have a strong reference somewhere to the second ViewController to which you are performing a segue which is not letting ARC to deallocate the ViewController.

Post the entire code so that I can better analyze what might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you use some type of segue besides a push, then the previous view controllers will automatically be deallocated.  Try presenting the view controller like this:

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myVC") as! MyVCName
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Going by your method, will there be any animation? I want the transition to happen without any sort of animation.

Comment: no animation... passing false for the animated: parameter means no animation